# Chrome KeyLogger (for Educational purposes)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, keylogger

I am trying to develop a Chrome keylogger for educational purposes. The problem I am facing is that I am not sure how to capture the keys from different tabs. I have created a extension for the keylogger with a icon. When the icon is pressed; the background page is supposed to run and just alert the key string as they are pressed.

The code of the background page is:

```
<script>
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(currWin);
    document.onmousedown = currWin;
function getCurrWin()
{
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(currWin);
}

function currWin(tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
    alert(tab.title + " : " + tab.id);
    document.onkeypress = keylogger;
})
}

function keylogger(e)
{   if(e.keyCode==27)
    {
        alert('A');
    }
    else{
    logged_keys+=String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    alert(logged_keys);
}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `currWin(tab)`, `document` refers to the background page, and not the tab you selected. Therefore, you don't really attach to the right event.

You will have to use [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to get to the events in a tab.